# Search from sql

Tags: php, sql, search

I want to search elements from sql database, I tried with these code. But it showing error. What to do?

```
$search = "SELECT cat, `cast`, `year`, art FROM categories WHERE cat LIKE '%".$s."%' OR cast LIKE '%".$s."%'  ORDER BY id DESC;";
```

Comment: Show the error message.

Comment: its show You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: please add the full code

Answer (score 2):

`CAST()` is a mysql function, so you cant use it as a column name unless you enclose it within ` ` like you have after the `OR`. Try:

```
$search = "SELECT cat, `cast`, `year`, art FROM categories WHERE cat LIKE '%".$s."%' OR `cast` LIKE '%".$s."%'  ORDER BY id DESC;";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query.

`cast` is mysql reserved keyword and i've added `` in the where conditions.

```
$search = "SELECT cat, `cast`, `year`, art FROM categories WHERE (cat LIKE '%".$s."%' OR `cast` LIKE '%".$s."%') ORDER BY id DESC;";
```

Thanks

Comment: Check it properly "cast" is mysql reserved key word and i've added `` in the where conditions.

Comment: Please let me know now it's not working i'm glad to assist you!

Comment: i getting this error  : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1